# Does an AJAX request override another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic AJAX function which has many different modes (I call the function with different parameters and check via switch-case which mode has to be used) but when I call the AJAX function with different parameters directly one after another using the same XMLHttpRequest it seems that the second request overrides the first one.

Is that possible?

Here is a example for my function(EDIT):

```
$(function() {
    ajax("test_1");
    ajax("test_2");
});

function ajax(mode)
    {
        switch (mode)
        {
            case "test_1":
                request = null;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    try {
                        request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                    } catch (e) {
                        try {
                            request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!request) {
                    console.log("Kann keine XMLHTTP-Instanz erzeugen");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    var url = "../ajax.php";
                    request.open('POST', url, true);
                    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    request.send('ajax_mode=test&request_mode=test_1');
                    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (request.readyState === 4)
                        {
                            interpretRequest_test_1();
                        }
                    };
                }
                break;
            case "test_2":
                request = null;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    try {
                        request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                    } catch (e) {
                        try {
                            request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!request) {
                    console.log("Kann keine XMLHTTP-Instanz erzeugen");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    var url = "../ajax.php";
                    request.open('POST', url, true);
                    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    request.send('ajax_mode=test&request_mode=test_2');
                    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (request.readyState === 4)
                        {
                            interpretRequest_test_2();
                        }
                    };
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    function interpretRequest_test_1() {
        if (request.status != 200) {
            console.log("Error");
        } else {
            alert("1");
        }
    }
    function interpretRequest_test_2() {
        if (request.status != 200) {
            console.log("Error");
        } else {
            alert("2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: look in browser console network tab. Both requests are being made, how you handle responses may be the issue but code provided doesn't tell us anything

Comment: your mode switching function must be in sync with ajax response. Otherwise it will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `request` variable isn't defined using the `var` keyword, which makes it a global and thus you are reusing the same XHR object.

If you are reusing the same XMLHttpRequest object then yes, it will abort the previous request if you try to make another request with it, while the other request is in progress.

In your switch statements, define `request` with the `var` keyword. This makes the variable scoped to the local scope, and not a global.

```
switch (mode) {
   case "test_1":
       var request = null;
       ...
   case "test_2":
       var request = null;
       ...
}
```

Alternatively do it just once at the top of your function instead of in each case statement.

A more simplified example if you have a global object:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function do_smth(){
    xhr.open(...);
}

function do_smth2(){
    xhr.open(...);
}

do_smth();
do_smth2();
```

Instead of a global, you need to make the XHR object scoped properly so each call has a unique XHR.

```
function do_smth(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(...);
}

function do_smth2(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(...);
}
```

Comment: my request variable is global defined.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `var request = null;` in the case statements.